# Does the set of Differentiable functions change if we change our norm?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

This may be a naive question. I am reading the definition of differetiablity of a function $f:\mathbb{R^n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R^m}$ in the book Calculus Manifolds. I already know that all norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$ induce the same metric topology. If we change the norms in the definition (for example we can use the manhattan norm), does the set of differentiable functions change ?

I already know that all norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$ induce the same metric topology but that doesn't seem to imply a negative answer to my question.

Another Question: If the set of differentiable functions changes, is there any reason why we are defining differentiablity using the Pythagorean norm ?

Thank you

Comment: You already received good answers, which completely solve your problem. From a somewhat more general point of view, the class of differentiable functions on a *smooth manifold* is completely determined and determines the *smooth structure* that is posed on it. This is one of the problems of a discipline called *differentiable topology*. In the case of finite-dimensional real vector spaces, the problem is trivial as there is only one smooth structure that one may pose on such a space while retaining differentiability of linear coordinate systems. (My 2 cents)

Comment: In infinite dimensions... not so simple.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thanks for your useful comment

Comment: @JamesS.Cook Is there a definition of differentiation for functions in an infinite number of variables. I t will now depend on the norm, but I would like to see some examples other than the trivial ones

Comment: @Amr indeed there is, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative I believe, convergence of a given series may differ for different choices of norm. This issue will distinguish differentiability w.r.t. differing norms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is independent of the norm! It follows directly from the equivalence of norms.
*Hint:* convergence is independent of the choice of the norm, by equivalence of norms.

Comment: Seems like I am missing something obvious

Comment: Equivalence of norms here means: 1) They induce the same metric topology or 2) There are two positive constants $C_1,C_2$ such that  the ratio of norms lies in $[C_1,C_2]$ for every vector $x$ ?

Comment: @Amr I'm confused too - what I understand equivalence of norms to mean is the 2) that you listed, and in this sense I don't believe all norms in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are equivalent.

Comment: it means: http://planetmath.org/equivalentnorms

Comment: @Karl Then I agree.

Comment: I think I only saw a proof that all norms are equivalent according to 1) the weaker sense

Comment: Are all norms equivalent in the sense of 2) ?

Answer (score 2):

Convergence in one norm is equivalent to convergence in any other norm.

Differentiability is defined by a limit, therefore by a concept of "convergence". Everytime you write $$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = f'(x)$$ you're saying

$$\left\| \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} - f'(x) \right\| \to 0$$

so apply norm equivalence and you're done.

Comment: For 1D I agree because you can group every thing under one norm, but for a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ do we get the same thing if we change norms ?

Comment: Yes, that was just an example to clarify what I was talking about. Think this way: limites are defined by the topology, and as you said all norms induce the same topology. So how can limits be different?

Comment: By a topology argument, I will be worried about taking quotients, but if equivalence means a constants of proportionality (not the right term but close) then I wouldn't be worried about quotients

Comment: Anyways Karl made it clear to me, thanks for your help as well